# Reading Csv into namedtuple

Tags: python, csv, namedtuple

I am trying to load the csv file I got from here: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data I have rewritten this dozen of times and now I am getting error saying list index out of range. Which baffles me completely since len(row) is 15. I must be missing something obvious here.

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple

fields = ('age', 
      'workclass', 
      'fnlwgt', 
      'education', 
      'education_num', 
      'marital_status', 
      'occupation', 
      'relationship', 
      'race', 
      'sex', 
      'capital_gain', 
      'capital_loss', 
      'hours_per_week', 
      'native_country', 
      'target')

CensusRecord = namedtuple('CensusRecord', fields)

with open("./data/adult_data.csv","r") as f:
     r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

     for row in r:
           data.append(CensusRecord(
           age              = int(row[0]),
           workclass        = row[1].strip(),
           fnlwgt           = float(row[2].strip()),
           education        = row[3].strip(),
           education_num    = int(row[4]),
           marital_status   = row[5].strip(),
           occupation       = row[6].strip(),
           relationship     = row[7].strip(),
           race             = row[7].strip(),
           sex              = row[9].strip(),
           capital_gain     = int(row[10]),
           capital_loss     = int(row[11]),
           hours_per_week   = int(row[12]),
           native_country   = row[13].strip(),
           target           = row[14].strip()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the data set with a text editor, and delete the blank lines at the end of the document. Then run your code

Comment: You are the hero. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a syntax error in my opinion : you should do...

```
data.append(CensusRecord("age" = <your_data>, ...)
```

Instead of

```
data.append(CensusRecord(age = <your data>, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, for help but nix found what was the problem. It was empty lines at the bottom of my csv.